# Invalid redirect url after open auth 2.0 authentication via Google

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement authentication in my MVC 3 web application via Google Open Auth 2.0. I've already successfully formed URL request URL and it looks like this:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1291/Account/Google/&response_type=token&client_id=MY_APP_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com

My expectation is to be redirected to the following URL:

http://localhost:1291/Account/Google?access_token=VALUE&token_type=VALUE&expires_in=VALUE

But actually I'm redirected here:

http://localhost:1291/Account/Google#access_token=VALUE&token_type=VALUE&expires_in=VALUE

The only difference is in "#" and "?" and without question mark I don't see query string parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to change the "response_type" from "token" to the "code" and the "#" symbol was successfully replaced with "?" and now I can extract the "code" from the query string. So, it was my fault. "response_type=token" is suggested to use with client js. More details here:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login  (Javascript Responses section)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar feature working in my application.  The only difference I can see is the trailing `/` in your `redirect_uri`?  Try:

> redirect_uri=http://localhost:1291/Account/Google

Comment: I already tried this variant, I also tried explicitly add question mark and change url the something like: redirect_uri=http://localhost:1291/Account/Google.php or redirect_uri=http://localhost:1291/Account/Google.php? - nothing helped